# Was the Jenkins Continuous Build Integration server named after Tom Jenkins, Thomas Jefferson's slave master?

Tags: history, united-states, slavery

I heard this rumor today and I was wondering if there is any truth to it. I guess there are two parts to it:

1. Did Thomas Jefferson have a slave master named Tom/Thom/Thomas Jenkins?
2. Was the Jenkins CI server named after this person?

I tried to research this but came up with conflicting information.

Comment: Can you link to this claim somewhere?

Comment: Also note that #2 isn't actually dependent upon #1... The server could have been named after someone was believed to be Jefferson's slave, but who either did not exist, or who did exist but was not a slave of Mr. Jefferson.

Comment: @Flimzy I tried to find the forum post where I read this (and it had a reference link) but now I can't find it. If I do find it again I'll update my original post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [stated reason](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/hudsons-future) the name Jenkins was chosen is because:

> ... the choice for a new name is Jenkins, which we think evokes the same sort of English butler feel as Hudson.

No official recognition of a slave by the name Jenkins is made.

Any further claim that the true/hidden reason has to do with a slave would be a question of motivation, and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: Jenkins is certainly a stereotypical butler name to my mind. I tried to figure out why that was, and the best I could come up with is that Daphne from the Scooby Doo cartoon once had a butler called Jenkins. I'm not sure if that is the origin of the cultural association.